# Basic linux commands (sudo/apt-get/nano) not found

Tags: command-line, terminal, sudo, nano

I'm using Linux sa515 on this application processor but I can't seem to run any of the following commands:

```
sudo
apt-get
nano
```

It says the corresponding command is not found. Am I missing something?

Comment: Those things may be simply not there, especially for Linux running on an embedded device.  Remember that "Linux", per se, is just the kernel - whatever else is available depends on how the software for this device is packaged.  The vendor (which I think is Qualcomm in your case) may not have thought that an embedded device that probably isn't supporting interactive users would need `sudo`, or a complex text editor, or a package manager...   There's probably not going to be a lot there other than whatever is necessary for the device to run a dedicated application.

Comment: I see. but say you want to edit some files or configure wifi. there's no way you can do it?

Comment: I don't know enough about this product (meaning: I know nothing specific about it, and most info seems to be locked away on Qualcomm's site and you need an account to get to it...) to say if there's "no way you can do it" or not.  There might be other tools you can use - e.g., instead of `sudo`, do they include `su`?  Instead of `nano`, do they include a simple editor like `ed`?  It looks like there is a cross-development environment you can run on Linux or Windows, so you can probably build what you need and load it on to the device.  Again, don't know enough detail to say much more than that

Comment: What directories are in your `$PATH`? Are the tools you want in `/sbin` or `/usr/sbin`?

Answer (score 1):

looks like I'd have to edit the files in the host and copy back over once done. it's a yocto based image and doesn't support all the commands.